# Thymeleaf single quote in validation error message

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using validation-api to validate if input field doesn't contain illegal characters: < > ' " etc. I'm using @Pattern annotation with custom message translated to something like this: The following signs < > " ' „  are not allowed. When this message is printed the single quote char is missing. I have: The following signs < > " „  are not allowed.

I've tried using \' and \u0027 and ' in the message.properties but with no success (in third case in the message there is fragment ').
Messages are displayed using:

```
<p class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('company.name')}" th:errors="${company.name}">error</p>
```

Thymeleaf version: 2.1.3.RELEASE

Spring version: 3.2.8.RELEASE

Spring webflow version: 2.4.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know much about Thymeleaft. But be aware that you might need to escape single quotes  (with two single quotes (`''`)) if you retrieve the message using `MessageFormat` and `ResourceBundle`.

If you are using Spring's `ResourceBundleMessageSource` (which uses `ResourceBundle` and `MessageFormat` internally) you have to do the same thing.

See [MessageFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

> Within a String, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any
>   arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string
>   "'{0}'" represents string "{0}", not a FormatElement. A single quote
>   itself must be represented by doubled single quotes '' throughout a
>   String. For example, pattern string "'{''}'" is interpreted as a
>   sequence of '{ (start of quoting and a left curly brace), '' (a single
>   quote), and }' (a right curly brace and end of quoting), not '{' and
>   '}' (quoted left and right curly braces): representing string "{'}",
>   not "{}".

Some time ago I wrote a blog post that provides some more details about exactly this topic: [Single quote escaping with Java resource bundles](http://www.mscharhag.com/2013/10/single-quote-escaping-in-java-resource.html)