# Validation message don't show single quote

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I am testing Spring:MVC validation tutorial. I used hibernate validator for bean validation as

```
@Min(value = 16, message = "Under 16 can't allow here.")
@Max(value = 100, message = "You are too old.")
private int age;
```

At my JSP file

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-2">Age : </label>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                <form:input path="age" class="form-control" cssStyle="width:50px" />
                <form:errors path="age" class="text-danger" />
            </div>              
        </div>
```

When I fill up value less than 16 , validation error message does not include **single-quote(')**. Check below screen shoot.

[image]

I am not sure which is the error , due to JSP or Hibernate or Spring MVC.
How can I solve to show single quote ?

Comment: What does the `BindingResult` contain when you submit the form? Each error has something like a "default message" and other info to do localization of error messages.

Comment: Right, I also suggest you step through the code with a debugger and inspect BindingResult and ConstraintViolation(Exception).  I would be surprised if the underlying ConstraintViolation does not contains the quote. If it does not, you probably want to raise a bug in Hibernate Validator. My guess would be the problem is somewhere in the rendering code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use ' you need to escape it using '.
So your error message should be like "Under 16 can''t allow here."

[Thymeleaf single quote in validation error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261820/thymeleaf-single-quote-in-validation-error-message)